# Javascript change text on label with for

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i need change text via Javacript in this labels. Labels have not class or id, only atribute for. Can you help me why?

```
<label for="phone">Phone<span class="red"><strong>*</strong></span></label>
```

I try this, but this change text in all labels at form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ $('label').html('Phone to work'); });
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select it using the attribute and value...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('label[for=phone]').html('Phone to work');
});
```

Comment: Yes, which is what the OP has posted.  Their problem is about locating the label.... `I try this, but this change text in all labels at form.`

Comment: True, although I have a strong feeling that OP would still like the asterisk in place.

Comment: I see your point, but haven't addressed that as they're quite specific about their current problem.  If they express that desire then I'll add the span tag to the answer :)

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you.

Comment: No worries - happy to help.  Is the above-mentioned point an issue (removing the asterisk)?

Comment: Please again, how change text in input with id?
       <td class="company-shopping"><label class="fix-input"><input    id="company-shopping" value="abc" type="checkbox"> Nakupuji na firmu</label></td>

Comment: That's a completely different scenario since the label doesn't have anything unique, and the checkbox is inside it.  You should fix the html so the checkbox isn't inside the label and it will be easier.

Comment: I know, this is second thing, but i dont create next questions, can you help me? Thx

Comment: I'm not saying make a new question - I'm saying your html is wrong and you need to fix that first.  That being said, I do think you should make a new question as you are asking for something different now.

Comment: `<td class="company-shopping"><label class="fix-input"><input id="company-shopping" value="abc" type="checkbox"> Nakupuji na firmu</label></td>`

Comment: Change it to this `<td class="company-shopping"><label class="fix-input" for="company-shopping">Nakupuji na firmu</label><input id="company-shopping" value="abc" type="checkbox"> </td>`  then you can use the same code as in this answer, but change the attribute value.

Comment: I cant change html, sorry, this is finish website. I change only via JS. I need only text from "Nakupuji na firmu" to "xxx".

Comment: Use the answer from Satpal as that shows how to change the text without changing anything else.  If you use my answer it will delete the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get the target the `<span>` element, then use `previousSibling` to get the TEXT_NODE then set it value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var spanDOMElement = $('label[for=phone] span.red').get(0); //Get the refernce to DOM element
  spanDOMElement.previousSibling.nodeValue = 'Phone to work';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="phone">Phone<span class="red"><strong>*</strong></span></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your need i think you can try this to solve your problem

```
<label for="phone">Phone<span class="red"><strong>*</strong></span></label>
<br>
<label for="cell">Phone<span class="red"><strong>*</strong></span></label> 

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("label[for=phone]").text('Phone to work'); 

  });
```